# my get recipe buttons aren't bringing me to the external page where the recipes are

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a meal generator and when the meals are pulled down from the API I get a recipe button is under each meal produced. The buttons should be clickable and bring you to an external webpage. If i right click the butt and click open in new tab the website opens. If i just click the link nothing happens. Here is the javascript code

```js
function getMealList(){
    let searchInputTxt = document.getElementById('search-input').value.trim();
    fetch(`https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com/recipes/mealplans/generate?timeFrame=day&targetCalories?q=${searchInputTxt}`, {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "81022d9c79mshc06abb7d77ff30fp1e6950jsncae6e5e16400"
    }}).then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        let html = "";
        if(data.meals){
            data.meals.forEach(meal => {
                html += `
                    <div class = "meal-item" data-id = "${meal.id}">
                        <div class = "meal-img">
                            <img src="https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/${meal.id}-556x370.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class = "meal-name">
                            <h3>${meal.title}</h3>
                            <a href = ${meal.sourceUrl} class = "recipe-btn">Get Recipe</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                `;
            });
            mealList.classList.remove('notFound');
        } else{
            html = "Sorry, we didn't find any meal!";
            mealList.classList.add('notFound');
        }

        mealList.innerHTML = html;
    });
}
```

I have embedded html code inside as shown above. Ive tried target="_blank" but still the same Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It might have to do with the dynamic nature of your html.  Try saving the sourceUrl in a data variable and use event delegation for an event listener that opens the page on click.

Comment: Hey @aidan do you have an example how the content of "meal.sourceUrl" looks like? does it have a protocol prepended ?

Answer (score 0):

Your API returns links with the `http` protocol; presumably you're using `https` for your site.   A simple fix is to modify to a protocol-neutral URL before embedding it in the page:

```js
const mealList = document.getElementById('mealList')

function getMealList() {
  let searchInputTxt = document.getElementById('search-input').value.trim();
  fetch(`https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com/recipes/mealplans/generate?timeFrame=day&targetCalories?q=${searchInputTxt}`, {
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "81022d9c79mshc06abb7d77ff30fp1e6950jsncae6e5e16400"
      }
    }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      let html = "";
      if (data.meals) {
        data.meals.forEach(meal => {
          // remove the http protocol:
          meal.trimmedUrl = meal.sourceUrl.replace(/^http:/, '');
          html += `
                    <div class = "meal-item" data-id = "${meal.id}">
                        <div class = "meal-img">
                            <img src="https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/${meal.id}-556x370.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class = "meal-name">
                            <h3>${meal.title}</h3>
                            <a href = "${meal.trimmedUrl}" class = "recipe-btn">Get Recipe</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                `;
        });
        mealList.classList.remove('notFound');
      } else {
        html = "Sorry, we didn't find any meal!";
        mealList.classList.add('notFound');
      }

      mealList.innerHTML = html;
    });
}
```

```html
<div id="mealList"></div>

<input id="search-input"><button onclick="getMealList()">go</button>
```